# How to show images in div that stored in db

Tags: java, ajax, image, database

I decided to store uploaded to servlet pictures in DB. But how to show them in browser (in particular div with css image-background style) without page reload?

In details: I have an full-AJAX web client that works with java servlet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a servlet that accepts a name / id uniquely identifying the picture as a GET parameter
2. Let the servlet load the picture from DB (as byte array or better - as stream)
3. Stream the picture using `response.getOutputStream()`
4. Don't forget to set the content-type to `image/png` or `image/jpeg`
5. Refer to the image in the css with `url: imageServlet?id=13214`